# How can I get roles or groups from Azure SAML 2.0 Application in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a spring boot application where I need to limit access for specific endpoints. So far I can authenticate against Azure using SAML 2.0.

This is the main configuration of the authentication in Spring

```html
@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());

  http
    .csrf()
    .disable();


  http
    .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

  http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();

  http
    .logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

 }
```

in Azure I have added the roles to the claim values as shown in the image below

[Azure Claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6T86.png)

My target is to be able evantaully to do something like the following:

```html
@GetMapping("/")
 @PreAuthorize("hasRole('User')")
 public String getSample(Principal principal) {
  log.info("Get Request");
  return "Hello";
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next step would be to implement your own `SAMLUserDetailsService` that would return the corresponding `UserDetail` instance with the rights `Authorities` granted to the user.

You would have to retrieve the list of Azure role from the SAMLCredential (something like `credential.getAtttributeAsString(<your_attribute_name>)` then you would have to map theses values with the list of authorities defined in your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, searched for that and worked for me.